# Using 3D arrays — can't make the output

Tags: c, arrays, string, for-loop, multidimensional-array

I have to make a program that read the input from the keyboard.  It includes uppercase and lowercase letters, all signs and numbers and every one of these characters to be made from asterisks and to appear in one line. I am working only with two letters to see how is it working, but I get really confused.

My code doesn't work at all, I have no idea how to do it. Printing out the arrays seems very hard for me and also to be in one line. I need to use only `while`, `for`, `return`, `break`, `continue`, `if`, `else`, `switch`, `case`, `default`, and the very easy codes that are for beginners.

```
    #include<stdio.h>
    #include<string.h>

    char line[100]={'A','B'};
    int i;
    const int nGlyphs = 1;
    const int nRow = 7;
    const int nChar = 6;
    const char alphabet[nGlyphs][nRows][nChar]={ 
    alphabet[0]= {
    "  *  ",
    " * * ",
    "*   *",
    "*   *",
    "*****",
    "*   *",
    "*   *"
    },
    {
    "***  ",
    "*  * ",
    "*  * ",
    "* *  ",
    "*   *",
    "*   *",
    "**** "}
    };

   int main(int argc, char *argv[])
   {
   printf("Type a word or number, or both: ");
   scanf("%s",line[i]);
   for (i = 0; i < 100; i++);
   {
    for (nRows = 0; nRows < 7; nRows++);
    {

    printf("%s\n",alphabet[nGlyphs]);


     }
  }     

 return (0);
 }
```

Comment: You need to try a little harder. For example, the first error from the compiler says *"use of undeclared identifier 'nGlyphs'"*. You need to figure that out and fix it. Then move on to the next compiler error, until you find a compiler error that you can't fix on your own.

Comment: sorry about that, it was "nGlyphs", but started making changes and forgot to turn the original code

Comment: Ok, but the point was that you should post code that has 0 errors and 0 warnings. You've got a long way to go.

Comment: that's the main problem, I can't get out from the problems

Comment: Yep, that's part of the learning process. Two techniques that are useful. 1) Only look at the **first** warning or error from the compiler. Fix it, and then run the compiler again. C compilers are notorious for going bonkers after the first error. 2) Compile early and often. For example, put a semicolon after `[nChar]` on line 9, and delete everything after that. Once you get that to compile, then add more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your fixed code.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

char line[100];

// C do not support 'const' keyword as array size specifier 
#define GLYPHS 2 // you use 2 glyphs instead 1
#define ROWS 7
#define CHARS 7 // extra char for whitespace

char alphabet[GLYPHS][ROWS][CHARS]={
    {
        "  *   ",
        " * *  ",
        "*   * ",
        "*   * ",
        "***** ",
        "*   * ",
        "*   * "
    },
    {
        "***   ",
        "*  *  ",
        "*  *  ",
        "* *   ",
        "*   * ",
        "*   * ",
        "****  "
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    printf("Type a word or number, or both: ");

    scanf("%s",line); // must be line instead line[0]

    for (i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) // ; must be removed otherwise loop has not body
    {
        for (j = 0; j < strlen(line); j++) // ; must be removed otherwise loop has not body
        {
                     // 'A' is the first array element
            printf("%s", alphabet[line[j] - 'A'][i]);
        }

        printf("\n");
    }
    return (0);
}
```

This code support only uppercase letters, but may be easly expanded to support other chars.

The example of implementation all printable chars by combination of bytes

```
#ifndef __FONT_H_INCL__
#define __FONT_H_INCL__

unsigned char font6_8[][6] =
{
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00 },   // sp
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x2f, 0x00, 0x00 },   // !
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x07, 0x00, 0x07, 0x00 },   // "
    { 0x00, 0x14, 0x7f, 0x14, 0x7f, 0x14 },   // #
    { 0x00, 0x24, 0x2a, 0x7f, 0x2a, 0x12 },   // $
    { 0x00, 0x62, 0x64, 0x08, 0x13, 0x23 },   // %
    { 0x00, 0x36, 0x49, 0x55, 0x22, 0x50 },   // &
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x05, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00 },   // '
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x1c, 0x22, 0x41, 0x00 },   // (
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x41, 0x22, 0x1c, 0x00 },   // )
    { 0x00, 0x14, 0x08, 0x3E, 0x08, 0x14 },   // *
    { 0x00, 0x08, 0x08, 0x3E, 0x08, 0x08 },   // +
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xA0, 0x60, 0x00 },   // ,
    { 0x00, 0x08, 0x08, 0x08, 0x08, 0x08 },   // -
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x60, 0x60, 0x00, 0x00 },   // .
    { 0x00, 0x20, 0x10, 0x08, 0x04, 0x02 },   // /
    { 0x00, 0x3E, 0x51, 0x49, 0x45, 0x3E },   // 0
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x42, 0x7F, 0x40, 0x00 },   // 1
    { 0x00, 0x42, 0x61, 0x51, 0x49, 0x46 },   // 2
    { 0x00, 0x21, 0x41, 0x45, 0x4B, 0x31 },   // 3
    { 0x00, 0x18, 0x14, 0x12, 0x7F, 0x10 },   // 4
    { 0x00, 0x27, 0x45, 0x45, 0x45, 0x39 },   // 5
    { 0x00, 0x3C, 0x4A, 0x49, 0x49, 0x30 },   // 6
    { 0x00, 0x01, 0x71, 0x09, 0x05, 0x03 },   // 7
    { 0x00, 0x36, 0x49, 0x49, 0x49, 0x36 },   // 8
    { 0x00, 0x06, 0x49, 0x49, 0x29, 0x1E },   // 9
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x36, 0x36, 0x00, 0x00 },   // :
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x56, 0x36, 0x00, 0x00 },   // ;
    { 0x00, 0x08, 0x14, 0x22, 0x41, 0x00 },   // <
    { 0x00, 0x14, 0x14, 0x14, 0x14, 0x14 },   // =
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x41, 0x22, 0x14, 0x08 },   // >
    { 0x00, 0x02, 0x01, 0x51, 0x09, 0x06 },   // ?
    { 0x00, 0x32, 0x49, 0x59, 0x51, 0x3E },   // @
    { 0x00, 0x7C, 0x12, 0x11, 0x12, 0x7C },   // A
    { 0x00, 0x7F, 0x49, 0x49, 0x49, 0x36 },   // B
    { 0x00, 0x3E, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x22 },   // C
    { 0x00, 0x7F, 0x41, 0x41, 0x22, 0x1C },   // D
    { 0x00, 0x7F, 0x49, 0x49, 0x49, 0x41 },   // E
    { 0x00, 0x7F, 0x09, 0x09, 0x09, 0x01 },   // F
    { 0x00, 0x3E, 0x41, 0x49, 0x49, 0x7A },   // G
    { 0x00, 0x7F, 0x08, 0x08, 0x08, 0x7F },   // H
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x41, 0x7F, 0x41, 0x00 },   // I
    { 0x00, 0x20, 0x40, 0x41, 0x3F, 0x01 },   // J
    { 0x00, 0x7F, 0x08, 0x14, 0x22, 0x41 },   // K
    { 0x00, 0x7F, 0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 0x40 },   // L
    { 0x00, 0x7F, 0x02, 0x0C, 0x02, 0x7F },   // M
    { 0x00, 0x7F, 0x04, 0x08, 0x10, 0x7F },   // N
    { 0x00, 0x3E, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x3E },   // O
    { 0x00, 0x7F, 0x09, 0x09, 0x09, 0x06 },   // P
    { 0x00, 0x3E, 0x41, 0x51, 0x21, 0x5E },   // Q
    { 0x00, 0x7F, 0x09, 0x19, 0x29, 0x46 },   // R
    { 0x00, 0x46, 0x49, 0x49, 0x49, 0x31 },   // S
    { 0x00, 0x01, 0x01, 0x7F, 0x01, 0x01 },   // T
    { 0x00, 0x3F, 0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 0x3F },   // U
    { 0x00, 0x1F, 0x20, 0x40, 0x20, 0x1F },   // V
    { 0x00, 0x3F, 0x40, 0x38, 0x40, 0x3F },   // W
    { 0x00, 0x63, 0x14, 0x08, 0x14, 0x63 },   // X
    { 0x00, 0x07, 0x08, 0x70, 0x08, 0x07 },   // Y
    { 0x00, 0x61, 0x51, 0x49, 0x45, 0x43 },   // Z
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x7F, 0x41, 0x41, 0x00 },   // [
    { 0x00, 0x55, 0x2A, 0x55, 0x2A, 0x55 },   // 55
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x41, 0x41, 0x7F, 0x00 },   // ]
    { 0x00, 0x04, 0x02, 0x01, 0x02, 0x04 },   // ^
    { 0x00, 0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 0x40 },   // _
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x04, 0x00 },   // '
    { 0x00, 0x20, 0x54, 0x54, 0x54, 0x78 },   // a
    { 0x00, 0x7F, 0x48, 0x44, 0x44, 0x38 },   // b
    { 0x00, 0x38, 0x44, 0x44, 0x44, 0x20 },   // c
    { 0x00, 0x38, 0x44, 0x44, 0x48, 0x7F },   // d
    { 0x00, 0x38, 0x54, 0x54, 0x54, 0x18 },   // e
    { 0x00, 0x08, 0x7E, 0x09, 0x01, 0x02 },   // f
    { 0x00, 0x18, 0xA4, 0xA4, 0xA4, 0x7C },   // g
    { 0x00, 0x7F, 0x08, 0x04, 0x04, 0x78 },   // h
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x44, 0x7D, 0x40, 0x00 },   // i
    { 0x00, 0x40, 0x80, 0x84, 0x7D, 0x00 },   // j
    { 0x00, 0x7F, 0x10, 0x28, 0x44, 0x00 },   // k
    { 0x00, 0x00, 0x41, 0x7F, 0x40, 0x00 },   // l
    { 0x00, 0x7C, 0x04, 0x18, 0x04, 0x78 },   // m
    { 0x00, 0x7C, 0x08, 0x04, 0x04, 0x78 },   // n
    { 0x00, 0x38, 0x44, 0x44, 0x44, 0x38 },   // o
    { 0x00, 0xFC, 0x24, 0x24, 0x24, 0x18 },   // p
    { 0x00, 0x18, 0x24, 0x24, 0x18, 0xFC },   // q
    { 0x00, 0x7C, 0x08, 0x04, 0x04, 0x08 },   // r
    { 0x00, 0x48, 0x54, 0x54, 0x54, 0x20 },   // s
    { 0x00, 0x04, 0x3F, 0x44, 0x40, 0x20 },   // t
    { 0x00, 0x3C, 0x40, 0x40, 0x20, 0x7C },   // u
    { 0x00, 0x1C, 0x20, 0x40, 0x20, 0x1C },   // v
    { 0x00, 0x3C, 0x40, 0x30, 0x40, 0x3C },   // w
    { 0x00, 0x44, 0x28, 0x10, 0x28, 0x44 },   // x
    { 0x00, 0x1C, 0xA0, 0xA0, 0xA0, 0x7C },   // y
    { 0x00, 0x44, 0x64, 0x54, 0x4C, 0x44 },   // z
    { 0x00,0x00, 0x06, 0x09, 0x09, 0x06 }    // horiz lines
};

#endif /* __FONT_H_INCL__ */
```

in your case it must be similar exept representation the characters
for example 'A'

```
    {
        "  *   ",
        " * *  ",
        "*   * ",
        "*   * ",
        "***** ",
        "*   * ",
        "*   * "
    },
```

instead of

```
{ 0x00, 0x7C, 0x12, 0x11, 0x12, 0x7C },
```

base character is selected as ' ' (whitespace).

in our case array declaration must bee like

```
unsigned char font6_8[][7][7] = { /* array elems .... */ }
```

example of array declaration

```
unsigned char glyphs[][7][7] =
    {
        {
            "      ",
            "      ",
            "      ",
            "      ",
            "      ",
            "      ",
            "      "
        },   // sp
        {
            "  *   ",
            "  *   ",
            "  *   ",
            "  *   ",
            "      ",
            "  *   ",
            "  *   "
        },   // !
        // .... elems .....
        {
            "  *   ",
            " * *  ",
            "*   * ",
            "*   * ",
            "***** ",
            "*   * ",
            "*   * "
        },   // A
        { 0x00, 0x7F, 0x49, 0x49, 0x49, 0x36 },   // B
        { 0x00, 0x3E, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x22 },   // C
        { 0x00, 0x7F, 0x41, 0x41, 0x22, 0x1C },   // D
        { 0x00, 0x7F, 0x49, 0x49, 0x49, 0x41 },   // E
        { 0x00, 0x7F, 0x09, 0x09, 0x09, 0x01 },   // F
        { 0x00, 0x3E, 0x41, 0x49, 0x49, 0x7A },   // G
        { 0x00, 0x7F, 0x08, 0x08, 0x08, 0x7F },   // H
        { 0x00, 0x00, 0x41, 0x7F, 0x41, 0x00 },   // I
        { 0x00, 0x20, 0x40, 0x41, 0x3F, 0x01 },   // J
        { 0x00, 0x7F, 0x08, 0x14, 0x22, 0x41 },   // K
        { 0x00, 0x7F, 0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 0x40 },   // L
        { 0x00, 0x7F, 0x02, 0x0C, 0x02, 0x7F },   // M
        { 0x00, 0x7F, 0x04, 0x08, 0x10, 0x7F },   // N
        { 0x00, 0x3E, 0x41, 0x41, 0x41, 0x3E },   // O
        { 0x00, 0x7F, 0x09, 0x09, 0x09, 0x06 },   // P
        { 0x00, 0x3E, 0x41, 0x51, 0x21, 0x5E },   // Q
        { 0x00, 0x7F, 0x09, 0x19, 0x29, 0x46 },   // R
        { 0x00, 0x46, 0x49, 0x49, 0x49, 0x31 },   // S
        { 0x00, 0x01, 0x01, 0x7F, 0x01, 0x01 },   // T
        { 0x00, 0x3F, 0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 0x3F },   // U
        { 0x00, 0x1F, 0x20, 0x40, 0x20, 0x1F },   // V
        { 0x00, 0x3F, 0x40, 0x38, 0x40, 0x3F },   // W
        { 0x00, 0x63, 0x14, 0x08, 0x14, 0x63 },   // X
        { 0x00, 0x07, 0x08, 0x70, 0x08, 0x07 },   // Y
        {
            "***** ",
            "   *  ",
            "  *   ",
            " *    ",
            "*     ",
            "*     ",
            "***** "
        },   // Z
        { 0x00, 0x00, 0x7F, 0x41, 0x41, 0x00 },   // [
        { 0x00, 0x55, 0x2A, 0x55, 0x2A, 0x55 },   // 55
        { 0x00, 0x00, 0x41, 0x41, 0x7F, 0x00 },   // ]
        { 0x00, 0x04, 0x02, 0x01, 0x02, 0x04 },   // ^
        { 0x00, 0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 0x40, 0x40 },   // _
        { 0x00, 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x04, 0x00 },   // '
        { 0x00, 0x20, 0x54, 0x54, 0x54, 0x78 },   // a
        { 0x00, 0x7F, 0x48, 0x44, 0x44, 0x38 },   // b
        { 0x00, 0x38, 0x44, 0x44, 0x44, 0x20 },   // c
        { 0x00, 0x38, 0x44, 0x44, 0x48, 0x7F },   // d
        { 0x00, 0x38, 0x54, 0x54, 0x54, 0x18 },   // e
        { 0x00, 0x08, 0x7E, 0x09, 0x01, 0x02 },   // f
        { 0x00, 0x18, 0xA4, 0xA4, 0xA4, 0x7C },   // g
        { 0x00, 0x7F, 0x08, 0x04, 0x04, 0x78 },   // h
        { 0x00, 0x00, 0x44, 0x7D, 0x40, 0x00 },   // i
        { 0x00, 0x40, 0x80, 0x84, 0x7D, 0x00 },   // j
        { 0x00, 0x7F, 0x10, 0x28, 0x44, 0x00 },   // k
        { 0x00, 0x00, 0x41, 0x7F, 0x40, 0x00 },   // l
        { 0x00, 0x7C, 0x04, 0x18, 0x04, 0x78 },   // m
        { 0x00, 0x7C, 0x08, 0x04, 0x04, 0x78 },   // n
        { 0x00, 0x38, 0x44, 0x44, 0x44, 0x38 },   // o
        { 0x00, 0xFC, 0x24, 0x24, 0x24, 0x18 },   // p
        { 0x00, 0x18, 0x24, 0x24, 0x18, 0xFC },   // q
        { 0x00, 0x7C, 0x08, 0x04, 0x04, 0x08 },   // r
        { 0x00, 0x48, 0x54, 0x54, 0x54, 0x20 },   // s
        { 0x00, 0x04, 0x3F, 0x44, 0x40, 0x20 },   // t
        { 0x00, 0x3C, 0x40, 0x40, 0x20, 0x7C },   // u
        { 0x00, 0x1C, 0x20, 0x40, 0x20, 0x1C },   // v
        { 0x00, 0x3C, 0x40, 0x30, 0x40, 0x3C },   // w
        { 0x00, 0x44, 0x28, 0x10, 0x28, 0x44 },   // x
        { 0x00, 0x1C, 0xA0, 0xA0, 0xA0, 0x7C },   // y
        { 0x00, 0x44, 0x64, 0x54, 0x4C, 0x44 },   // z
        { 0x00,0x00, 0x06, 0x09, 0x09, 0x06 }    // horiz lines
    };
```

so you myst just replace `{ 0x00,0x00, 0x06, 0x09, 0x09, 0x06 }` like values with your own glyphs.

Comment: You should explain what changes you made and why

Comment: Can someone help me in private, to ask some questions because I am a beginner and it is very hard to understad everything?

Comment: @Trex00:So what do you suggest?

Comment: Can you give me contacts ot something just to ask you? I am in a very hard situation

Comment: You can ask me here. Just comment in this or other my post with @Mykola to send a message to me.

Comment: @Trex00: Will help what i can.

Comment: This site also support confereces.

Comment: I want to write you in private, but don't know where to find it

Comment: @Mykola I can't understand this part " printf("%s", alphabet[line[j] - 'A'][i]);" and also when I compile the code it is said " incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘strlen’ " should it be separated the function strlen.

Comment: error with strlen is very odd, are you sure that you pasted my code correctly?

Comment: @Trex00: This error occures when, the compiler can not find function declaration in our case `strlen`. it is declared in `string.h` header file

Comment: @Trex00: check you include this file by `#include <string.h>`

Comment: @Mykola It worked I pasted some text with the code. So it works, but this part with the printf I can't understand, because I need to adjust the program to work with lowercase letters, signs and numbers. Because I am new to programming and I can't understand some things, sorry for bodering you.

Comment: @Trex00: alphabet[line[j] - 'A'][i] just selects the proper string from array you created. As the alphabeth starts with A, the character number also starts with 'A' and ends up with 'Z', so as our created array is in aphabethical  order alphabet[line[j] - 'A'][i] will defines our glyph posiition.

Comment: @Mykola So if I try to do it with the lowecase letters and signs I should do it the same way right. I will have another array for lowercase letters, for signs and numbers.

Comment: for example our string contain this info 'ABBAC', we can get any character number referencing to ASCII table http://cnautique-saintcast.com/tag-image-table-ascii__.html

Comment: as we se 'A' character have number 65

Comment: (decimal) its important

Comment: so if we substract 'A' from 'A' i.m. 65 - 65 we get 0.

Comment: it is the first element of our array.

Comment: for 'B' the number is 66 'B' - 'A' = 1 (second element)

Comment: so for input string 'ABBAC' we shall get 0,1,1,0,2

Comment: printable chars starts with 32 number whitespace ' '

Comment: Where did the other A came from "so if we substract {'A'} from 'A' i.m. 65 - 65 we get 0." I marked it with { }

Comment: It is came from our input string line[j]

Comment: we simply get the character from input string and substract from it our base character in our case 'A'

Comment: So I need to substract from 33 to appear "!", and then the rest

Comment: first we need to select base character

Comment: as I mentioned before for all printable chars base index is 32

Comment: so you 3d array must starts with ' ' (32) character up to 127

Comment: I actually have all the signs and numbers and letters made from asterisks, so if I implement them to the array will it work?

Comment: Yes, it is. You must define 95 separate array elements which represents printable chars by asperics and whitespaces

Comment: give me an example for 2 signs and numbers, just the array

Comment: 8 [1][7][7] and the next one will be 9[1][7][7], and the same with the signs

Comment: @Mykola sorry for the time I stole from you, and my stupid questions, my apologies

Comment: @Mykola, I can't do it this way, I am not allowed, I need to use simple codes and functions

Comment: @Mykola I can't use the codes you gave me for implementation, I have not studied, it is an assignment and it is my first month in university

Comment: I have update my answer to clear owerall situations with strange arrays.

Comment: To accept the answer simply click the accept icon under post rating. If you have reputation score of 15 you can also upvote posts. Accepting answer add +2 to reputation.

Comment: Upvoting is performed by simple click up arraw above post rating score.

Comment: @Trex00: Did you already figure out how to build this program.

Comment: @Mykola Could you show me how to write two letter in 3d array one next to other, because I need space in my code?

Comment: @Mykola And if I made all the letters in the 3d array one under other, how I am able to copy them to stadn next to each other, to have space. Because when I paste them the go very messy.

Comment: I think placing letters verticaly is the only way. Or you can place them in separate header file.

Comment: int arr[2][3][4] = { { {1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3, 4} },
                     { {1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2, 3, 4} } };

Comment: but it is posible but your code will looks like` { { "      ",  "      ",  "      ", "      ",  "      ", "      ",
            "      " }  // sp }`

Comment: @Trex00: placing letters verticaly will be much more informative.

Comment: @Trex00: big plus is you can easly edit your character patterns

Comment: @Trex00: Place whitespace character pattern and draw character picture by *.

Comment: @Trex00: You can also evict your array out of `main.cpp` by create file `glyphs.h` and paste your array there. After simply place created `glyphs.h` near `main.cpp` and include your array to main by directive #include "glyphs.h".

Comment: @Mykola Thats how I make them